# Python: How do you use a variable value in a Dict Call?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use a variable to set the Dict path for another variable:

```
podtype = "podcast1" #this changes based on what you select in the UI

client_config = {
podcast1: {
name: "test"
}
podcast2: {
name: "test"
}
}

podConif = client_config.podtype['name']  #I need the value of **podtype** in this code to dynamically select what part of the dict tree to grab.
```

Any ideas? I assume I need to wrap it in something like a get() wrapper?

Comment: `client_config[podtype]`?

Comment: `.` isn't used for dictionary elements, it's used for object attributes.

Comment: Are `podcast1` and `podcast2` variables? And if so what do they hold?

Comment: You seem to be confusing Python dictionaries with JavaScript objects.

Comment: @Barmar yes, I'm mainly a JS dev...

Comment: @jonrsharpe, that worked, thank you!!! I feel like an idiot!

Comment: It's the same syntax as JS, `.podtype` doesn't work with a variable in JS either whereas `[podtype]` does. It's just in Python you always have to use the bracket notation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, it was due to my mixing up JS object syntax and Py dicts.

This worked:

```
podConif = client_config[podtype]['name']
```